# Show that $\frac{dE}{dt}= - bv^2$

Tags: calculus

Show that the rate of change of energy in a damped oscillator is: $$\frac{dE}{dt}= - bv^2$$

Knowing the following:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{-k}{m}x-\frac{b}{m}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

I'm following my notes here, but can't understand some parts, here's the solution anyway:

$$\frac{dE}{dt}= \frac{1}{2}m(\frac{d}{dt}v^2) + \frac{1}{2}k(\frac{d}{dt}x^2)$$

For some reason the next step as follows:

$$\frac{dE}{dt}= \frac{1}{2}m(2v\frac{dv}{dt}) + \frac{1}{2}k(2x\frac{dx}{dt})$$

Why is it that the $v$ and $x$ are diffrentiated when it's with respect to $t$? if someone can elaborate on how my lecturer came to that I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those quantities are time dependent.
\begin{align}
x &= x(t) \\
v &= v(t) = \dot{x}(t) \\
a &= a(t) = \dot{v}(t) = \ddot{x}(t)
\end{align}
The constants regarding time are mass $m$ and the spring constant $k$.

Comment: That's understandable but shouldn't it be simply $2x$ as opposed to $2x\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: No, the chain rule $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ asks for $(d/dt)(x(t))^2= 2 x(t) \dot{x}(t)$.

Comment: $f(t) = t^2$, $g(t) = x(t)$. $h(t) = f(g(t)) = (x(t))^2$. $\dot{f}(t)=2t$. $\dot{h}(t) = \dot{f}(g(t)) \dot{g}(t) = 2g(t) \dot{g}(t) = 2x(t)\dot{x}(t)$.